# Any open octave development projects for mathematician/physicist programmers versus classdef?

Tags: octave

At first I was excited about working on open development projects for Octave related to implementing programs heavy in mathematics and physics, such as delaunayTriangulation class, but after talking to a few octave maintainers I have come to the sad conclusion that Octave   will be complete after classdef is complete, at which point physics or mathematician like programmers will no longer be needed to build new functionality to Octave. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed [your thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/developing-the-delaunayTriangulation-class-for-Octave-td4661795.html) on the Octave maintainers mailing list and I think you have misunderstood this quite badly.

Once `classdef` gets implemented, the problems won't be solved, quite the contrary. It will allow for many problems to be solved, which can't be done just yet in a Matlab compatible way. There are 2 things here:

- you may have felt that there's no problems left to solve after seeing many suggestions of libraries that already solve the problem. That doesn't mean they will be used. Even if licensing allows it, there comes a point where having to "reshape" the data in Octave into whatever form the other library uses it, is just too much and a native interface is preferred. This is specially true in Octave because it's mostly written in the Octave language which allows for users to participate in its development.
- Even if an external library is used in the end, remember that "the devil is in the details". Implementing an interface between Octave and an external library is not a trivial problem.

When classdef is complete, the work will start, not finish. And classdef is already working on the development version, so if you are interested in those classes, you could start implementing them there and they'd be released with the next version. To continue development of classdef, Octave needs that people it, so that it's problems can be found. And the delaunayTriangulation class requires classdef. It looks like a great pair, that should be developed together.